# Default Grafana Alerting templates

Tags: grafana, microsoft-teams, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I'm looking for the default templates that Grafana uses to send alert notifications... I'd like to make some changes but I couldn't find these templates anywhere to base myself on...

Does anyone know where the default grafana templates are?
I will use Telegram, Microsoft Teams and Email.

Default notifications template for Grafana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found in file `alerting/templates/default_template.go` within source code of Grafana. You can view it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/grafana/alerting/blob/main/templates/default_template.go).

Also link to it can be found on the page about [Notification templating](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/alert-rules/message-templating/) of official Grafana documentation, together with information on template usage and modification. Be sure to read it, before attempting modification.