# Grafana. Is it possible to remove attachment?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4c2.png)

[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNj7.png)

i can remove full information from title message and this attachment to notification will be as on the second screenshot
but I can’t find any information on how to remove this attachment to the message where you can see “Grafana v10.1.1”
( i just need 3 text strings without any attachments/blanks)

Can anyone paste here link on documentation or maybe someone saw similar problem
or maybe you have ready to use example?)

Read full documentation and typical templating problems but didnt find same problem(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default Grafana Alerting templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111697/default-grafana-alerting-templates)

Comment: unfortunately no. i use template and remove from it full information and leave empty like: 
{{ define "title2" }}
{{ end }}
but it sends that blank with Grafana version as you can see on screen 2
f.e.: if we use template {{ define "title" }}
  {{ range .Alerts }}
  {{.GeneratorURL}}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }} we will get attachment as you can see on screen 1 but i want remove it at all..